# Using Functions in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

The program I'm working on has two different functions, one that calculates the number of syllables in a text file, and another that calculates the readability of the text file based on the formula

```
206.835-85.6*(Number of Syllables/Number of Words)-1.015*(Number of Words/Number of   Sentences)
```

Here are the problems I'm having:

1. I'm supposed to display the contents of the text file in a multi-line text box.
2. I'm supposed to display the answer I get from the function `indexCalculation` in a label below the text box.
3. I'm having trouble calling the function to actually have the program calculate the answer to be displayed in the label.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
Option Strict On

Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Dim open As New OpenFileDialog

        open.Filter = "text files |project7.txt|All file |*.*"
        open.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)

        If open.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim selectedFileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(open.FileName)
            If selectedFileName.ToLower = "project7.txt" Then
                    Dim text As String = File.ReadAllText("Project7.txt")
                    Dim words = text.Split(" "c)
                    Dim wordCount As Integer = words.Length
                    Dim separators As Char() = {"."c, "!"c, "?"c, ":"c}
                    Dim sentences = text.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                Dim sentenceCount As Integer = sentences.Length
                Dim vowelCount As Integer = 0
                For Each word As String In words
                vowelCount += CountSyllables(word)
                Next
                vowelCount = CountSyllables(text)
                Label1.Show(indexCalculation(wordCount, sentenceCount, vowelCount))
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("You cannot use that file!")
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    Function CountSyllables(word As String) As Integer
        word = word.ToLower()
        Dim dipthongs = {"oo", "ou", "ie", "oi", "ea", "ee", _
                         "eu", "ai", "ua", "ue", "au", "io"}
        For Each dipthong In dipthongs
            word = word.Replace(dipthong, dipthong(0))
        Next
        Dim vowels = "aeiou"
        Dim vowelCount = 0
        For Each c In word
            If vowels.IndexOf(c) >= 0 Then vowelCount += 1
        Next
        If vowelCount = 0 Then
            vowelCount = 1
        End If
        Return vowelCount
    End Function

    Function indexCalculation(ByRef wordCount As Integer, ByRef sentenceCount As Integer, ByRef vowelCount As Integer) As Integer
        Dim answer As Integer = CInt(206.835 - 85.6 * (vowelCount / wordCount) - 1.015 * (wordCount / sentenceCount))
        Return answer
    End Function
End Class
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would rethink your answer variable in index calculation. Your casting it all as an integer, but you have mixed types. You have hardcoded values that are of type decimal and such, casting any of this as an integer will make you loose all precisions. Just a thought...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my suggestions:

1. update your indexCalculation function to take in Integers, not strings. that way you don't have to convert them to numbers.
2. remove all of your extra variables you are not using. this will clean things up a bit.
3. remove your streamreader. it appears you are reading the text via File.ReadAllText
4. Label1.Show(answer) should be changed to Label1.Show(indexCalculation(wordCount,sentenceCount,vowelCount)) -- unless Label1 is something other than a regular label, use Label1.Text = indexCalculation(wordCount,sentenceCount,vowelCount))

Then for the vowelCount, you need to do the following:

```
Dim vowelCount as Integer = 0
For Each word as String in words
 vowelCount += CountSyllables(word)
Next
```

Also, add the logic to the CountSyllables function to make it 1 if 0. If you don't want to include the last character in your vowel counting, then use a for loop instead of a for each loop and stop 1 character short.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful, now the only issue I'm having is on the vowelCount, it's saying it hasn't been declared, any ideas? Also, any suggestions as to how to get the contents of the file to show up in a multi-line text box?

Comment: Well, you would need to declare the variable and set it like so `Dim volwelCount as Integer = CountSyllables(text)`. Although I would probably change the function name to CountVowels because that is what you are returning.

Comment: Also, what is this supposed to do? `word = word.Replace(dipthong, dipthong(0))`? as it is now, it won't work since you are trying to reference the first item in dipthong, however that is not an array.

Comment: Well, the goal of the program is to count the words, sentences, and syllables from a text file and then apply those values to the formula and display the text of the file in a multi-line text box and the answer from the formula in the label. That was a suggestion that someone else gave me to count the syllables because I had no clue how that would be done.

Comment: okay. then i guess you are trying to do the following: `word = word.Replace(dipthong, "a")`. that essentially removes any of the multi-vowel pairs and replaces with a single one.

Comment: Yeah, I/m not really sure, here's what our professor gave us on how to count the syllables "Each group of adjacent vowels(a,e,i,o,u,y) counts as one syllable (for example, the "ea" in real contributes one syllable, but the "e...a" in regal counts as two syllables). However, an "e" at the end of a word does not count as a syllable. Also, each word has at least one syllable, even if the previous rules give it a count of zero."

Comment: I'm about to edit this post with the updated code, would you mind giving it a look to make sure I've done it correctly? Also, I'm now getting an error at the label1.Show portion of the code that says there are too many arguments.

Comment: Use `Label1.Text = indexCalculation(wordCount, sentenceCount, vowelCount).ToString()`

Comment: Also, remove the line `vowelCount = CountSyllables(text)`. you are already setting that variable correctly.

Comment: Awesome, it works! Thanks so much. Can you point me in the right direction on how to display the contents of the text file into the mult-line text box though?

Comment: first you need to have a textbox added to the form with multiline set to true (if i remember correctly). then you would just reference it like this (assuming TextBox1 is the name of the textbox): `TextBox1.Text = text`

Comment: @attila VB.Net supports local type inference for local variables which is on by default. Explicit typing is not required where you suggest it is. Please refer to the MSDN docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384937.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the read Phillip. I did not know about local type inference in VB. I have updated my answer.